# SSIS: What services to restart so Folder Permissions Propogate to username executing pacakge?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I created an SSIS package that needs access to a folder on a shared drive.

The package runs successfully on my local machine but I get an access denied error when I run it on a different server using a different username.

I created a ticket for IT to give access permissions to the user name that is executing the package but the package was still failing with same access to the path is denied error.

I was told by IT that I would need to restart the services that the (windows) username was using so that the changes would propagate.

My questions is, what services would I need to restart so that the username will have the new access rights propagated to it so that my package will run (with access to the folder)?

Do I need to restart the server that the package resides on? Does the server that contains the shared folder need to be restarted? Does some SQL Server service need to be restarted? What is the easiest way to have the permissions propagate to the username?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to get the changes to propagate by restarting just the 1 service that was being used by our DWH (under the username we wanted to give access to). So I guess the answer to my questions is that you only have to restart the 1 specific service that the username invokes when running the package. Restarting the entire server was not necessary.

I would have liked to have written a more detailed answer but the process was done by someone else and I was just watching as they did it so I did not get a chance to see exactly what service they restarted but I recall seeing Data Warehouse in the service name.